# Python check for duplicate and null values in two list and map them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two list of name and numbers which contains some blank and duplicate entries

```
phone = ['918222822','92929129','','92929129','','12345678','12345678','1727398','']
name  = ['jhon', 'ele', '' , 'ele', '' , 'rock','rock','','burh']
```

1. If you see most of the numbers map to a name.
2. There is a case where I have entry for number for blank for name or vice-versa.

This is what is have tried so far:

```
phone = ['918222822','92929129','','92929129','','12345678','12345678','1727398','']
name  = ['jhon', 'ele', '' , 'ele', '' , 'rock','rock','','burh']
phone = set(phone)
name = set(name)
for na, ph in zip(name,phone):
    if na is None:
       na = ph
    elif ph is None:
       #do something
       pass
    print(na,ph)
```

What I am trying to get as output is:

**Output**

```
jhon  918222822
ele   92929129
rock  12345678
1727398   1727398  # if number found but not name then put number in name
                   # if only name found but no corresponding number then delete entries in both list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both lists have the same length, just iterate over them and match their entries as you described:

```
from pprint import pprint

phone = ['918222822','92929129','','92929129','','12345678','12345678','1727398','']
name = ['jhon', 'ele', '' , 'ele', '' , 'rock','rock','','burh']

result = {}
removed = []
for idx, thephone in enumerate(phone):
    # If name is empty string, use phone as name
    thename = name[idx] if len(name[idx]) else thephone

    # If one of both still is empty string, skip the entry
    if not len(thename) or not len(thephone):
        # Store removed names for later processing;
        # Note that this also stores empty names that are pruned
        # Add conditional `if len(thename):` if they shall be skipped
        removed.append(thename)
        continue

    # If not already present, store values in dict
    if thename not in result.keys():
        result[thename] = thephone

pprint(result)
pprint(removed)
```

The result then is:

```
{'1727398': '1727398',
 'ele': '92929129',
 'jhon': '918222822',
 'rock': '12345678'}
['', '', 'burh']
```

Comment: can I get a deleted names e.g `bruh` in a list . I Just to keep a track

Comment: Sure; just add your code right before the `continue` statement. It is only executed (due to the prior in-line conditional) if the name is present but the number is empty. Add a new list to carry along and append `thename` to that list before `continue`.

Comment: Updated to carry along removed names.

Answer (score 1):

```
phone = ['918222822','92929129','','92929129','','12345678','12345678','1727398','']
name  = ['jhon', 'ele', '' , 'ele', '' , 'rock','rock','','burh']

res = set([i for i in zip(phone, name) if i[0]])
res = dict((i[0], i[1]) if i[1] else (i[0], i[0]) for i in res)
print(res.keys())   #phone
print(res.values())  #name
```

**Output:**

```
['1727398', '918222822', '12345678', '92929129']
['1727398', 'jhon', 'rock', 'ele']
```

Comment: Can you explain what is i[0] is doing. I am just a beginner and not good at  list comprehensions

Comment: I am checking if the second value in the tuple is empty if it is i am creating it populating it with the first value. Ex: `('1727398', '1727398')`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Btw I was looking for two separate lists. Like `print(phone,name)`

Comment: In that case you can convert it to a dict

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `defaultdict` to map all phone numbers corresponding to a name:

```
phone = ['918222822','92929129','','92929129','','12345678','12345678','1727398','']
name  = ['jhon', 'ele', '' , 'ele', '' , 'rock','rock','','burh']

phones = collections.defaultdict(list)
phones = collections.defaultdict(set)
for i, n in enumerate(name):
    phones[n].add(phone[i])

for n in phones:
    print(n , ":", ', '.join([ ph if ph != '' else "''" for ph in phones[n]]))
```

Output is:

```
jhon : 918222822
ele : 92929129
 : '', 1727398
rock : 12345678
burh : ''
```

Output may not be exactly what you want, but since it is now a mapping it is easy to postprocess it.